# Latex-Python combination not running on a mac

Tags: texlive, mactex, python

I am a beginner in Latex/Python and try to run the file below on my Mac (10.8.4 - latest MacTex). This is just a test file and it is not running. Python is running in the console and I have copied python.sty into the folder "library/texmf".

Can you tell me what the problem might be? Would be really helpful. I couldnt find any solution on the internet. Thanks in advance!!!

Andreas

CODE

```
%& -shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

\begin{python}%
print "hi"
\end{python}%

\end{document}
```

Message from Latex

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./Ohne-Titel.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <3.9f> and hyphenation patterns for 78 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/python/python.sty)
(./Ohne-Titel.aux)
! I can't find file `Ohne-Titel.py.out'.
<to be read again> 
                   \def 
l.10 \end{python}
                 %
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name:
```

Comment: I don't think that `%& -shell-escape` is sufficient to enable shell escape and the second line in the log file confirms it: `restricted` should not appear in that case. Are you calling `xelatex` from the terminal or from a front-end such as TeXShop?

Comment: I am using TexWorks with xelatex. And for the first sentence: I have to admit that I just copied the file and tried to run it.

Answer (score 4):

The `%& -shell-escape` first line is not sufficient to enable shell escape with TeX Live (MacTeX). This is confirmed by your log: you have

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

while it should be

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-0.9999.3 (TeX Live 2013)
 \write18 enabled.
```

with shell escape enabled.

---

Here's how you can do with TeXworks.

Open the Preferences panel in TeXworks and go to the Typesetting tab

[image]

Click on the “+” button in the lower part

Now fill in the “Tool configuration” window as shown below

[image]

For adding a line in the “Arguments” section, click on the “+” button (three times, in this case).

Use the following first line in your document

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX+shell-escape
```

so that the typesetting tool will be the one just created.

The complete file will then be

```
% !TEX program = XeLaTeX+shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{python}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

\begin{python}%
print "hi"
\end{python}%

\end{document}
```

Here's the result after hitting the “compile” button:

[image]

You *might* add the `--shell-escape` argument to the standard XeLaTeX tool, but it's better not doing it, as shell escape should be enabled with caution only for “safe” file (your files or those coming from a trusted source).