# Why this LaTeX-Python not loading Graphics in OS X?

Tags: graphics, mac, python

Code [deprecated; see revision 2] which I run with XeLaTeX--shell-escape in TextMate of OS X 10.11.4 El Capitan

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{python} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53465/13173
%% OS X http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136318/13173
% XeLaTeX--shell-escape

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
import os
directory = "/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps"
extension = ".eps"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

for file in files:
   if 
   print r"\begin{figure}"
   print r"\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{%s}" % file
   print r"\caption{File %s}" % file
   print r"\label{Serie%s}" % file
   print r"\end{figure}"
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

Expected out is some pictures. 
I see in logs that figures are correctly loaded. 
However, the output is a blank document with a pagenumber without pictures.

### Revision 2 after egrep

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{python} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53465/13173
%% OS X http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136318/13173
% XeLaTeX--shell-escape

\graphicspath{{/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps}}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
import os
directory = "/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps"
extension = ".eps"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

for file in files:
   print r"\begin{figure}"
   print r"\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{%s}" % file
   print r"\caption{File %s}" % file
   print r"\label{Serie%s}" % file
   print r"\end{figure}"
\end{python}

\end{document}
```

but still same output. 
Content in `.py.out`

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{test.eps}
\caption{File test.eps}
\label{Serietest.eps}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{test2.eps}
\caption{File test2.eps}
\label{Serietest2.eps}
\end{figure}
```

which is correct. 
In logs after `runsystem`

```
(./test.py.out
^^JLaTeX Warning: File `test.eps' not found on input line 2.^^J
./test.py.out:2: Unable to load picture or PDF file 'test.eps'.
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.2 ...cale=0.3]{test.eps}

The requested image couldn't be read because
it was not a recognized image format.
```

This is strange because I could load the .eps image individually in the document before setting up Python in the processing.
However, removing option `--shel-escape` does not lead to expected output anymore.

### Test without Python

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps/}}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{test.eps}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Errors

```
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class

Latex Error: ./test.tex:6 Unable to load picture or PDF file '/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps/test.eps'.

Including: "/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps/test.eps"
Latex Error: ./test.tex:6 Unable to load picture or PDF file '/Users/masi/Desktop/testEps/eps/test.eps'.

Latex Error: ./test.tex:8 Output loop---100 consecutive dead cycles.
```

This is a strange behaviour where the removal of Python did not help. 
Either Python strange something in the system or I have some bug, which I have not noticed. 
I do not understand the error `100 consecutive dead cycles`.

---

Why is there no output of figures in the case?

Comment: I get the images. What's in the `.py.out` file?

Comment: @egreg `.py.out` is correct. See the body.

Comment: Please add the relevant part of the log, after `runsystem`

Comment: @egreg I added the relevant part of the log, which is surprising to me. I also added a simpler test case, which is more surprising to me. This situation did not occur before when I did not use Python inside the code with the same figures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a stray `if` in the Python code. You're also missing `\graphicspath`.

In the code below I masked off the real path I used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{python} % http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53465/13173
%% OS X http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/136318/13173
% XeLaTeX--shell-escape

\graphicspath{{<maskedInformation>/testeps/}}

\begin{document}

\begin{python}
import os
directory = "<maskedInformation>/testeps/"
extension = ".eps"
files = [file for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.lower().endswith(extension)]

for file in files:
   print r"\begin{figure}"
   print r"\includegraphics[scale=0.3]{%s}" % file
   print r"\caption{File %s}" % file
   print r"\label{Serie%s}" % file
   print r"\end{figure}"
\end{python}

\end{document}
```