# Executing python script or code using \input not working

Tags: pdftex, input, python

Im trying to execute a python script from within LaTeX by means of using the \input command, however I get a strange error that I can't really understand. Im following the working example taken from this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/598404/33245) but it simply won't work.

**Example 1**: `\input{|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}` gives the error ! LaTeX Error: File `|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'.tex' not found.
Note there's a tilde there after just before the |

**Example 2**: `\input{|python3 test.py}` gives the error ! LaTeX Error: File `|python3 test.py' not found.

Note again there's a tilde there after just before the |

Im currently using PDFLaTeX with the --shell-escape flag, but I can't really make it work.

What am I doing wrong? Here is the full code:

```
\documentclass[10pt, export]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=-2cm, right=0cm, paperwidth=12in, paperheight=6.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

\input{|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}
\input{|python3 test.py}

\end{document}
```

Best regards and thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**

Trying David's answer produces this output:

```
! LaTeX Error: File `|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'.tex' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: tex)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 
         
l.10 1+2 = \input{|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}
                                           ^^M
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

These are the flags I'm using with PDFLatex under Kile:

```
--shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %source
```

The same is output when compiled from the terminal as follows:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode test.tex
```

Comment: I don't see a tilde `~` do you mean the left quote `\`` ?  Have you used `pdflatex --shell-escape` to allow python to run?

Comment: Hello @DavidCarlisle, thanks for your answer. Yes, I meant the left quote (I can't reproduce it on my spanish keyboard :(  ) As I described in my question Im using the --shell-escape both in kile as well as from the terminal (tried both).

Comment: `^^M` rather unexpected, have you transferred the file from windows?

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. I work under Debian Testing only. No Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works if you use TeX's primitive `\input`, which is saved in LaTeX as `\@@input`:

This is `script.py`:

```python
print("Number four: %d." % 4)
```

This works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter  % to use \@@input
\def\runshell#1{%
    \@@input"|#1"\relax
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
a\runshell{python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}b

a\runshell{python3 script.py}b

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it works with latex input as well

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
a\input{|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}b

a\input{|python3 script.py}b
\end{document}`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried your solution and it works, but I can't really understand why it won't work as in @DavidCarlisle's answer. I will be marking this as solved, until I get new updates.

Answer (score 1):

You need `--shell-escape` and remove the geometry setting which is forcing the text off the page;

```
\documentclass[10pt, export]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage[left=0cm, top=0cm, bottom=-2cm, right=0cm, paperwidth=12in, paperheight=6.75in]{geometry}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}

1+2 = \input{|python3 -c 'print(1+2)'}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your example but it won't work. The problem persists. Im currently using debian testing and Im starting to wonder if this could be the reason behind the problem.

Comment: @Charlie this works, as does the version I added as a comment in the other answer, you could show the log you get from this answer

Comment: @Charlie if you have an old latex you may need double quotes as used in the other answer  so `\input{"|......."}`

Comment: please see my updated answer. BTW: I have tried double quotes as well, but nothing changed :( thanks for the tip though.